# Treasury stock and the Accounting equation

Tags: accounting

What happens to assets and liabilities when treasury stock is cancelled after a buy back?

```
A - L = E
```

When treasury stock is cancelled it encreases equity and for the equation to balance something must happen to either assets, liabilities or both. Can you explain which is which and why?

**Example**

Let's say that we have a company with US$1 Million in treasury stock in the equity section of the balance sheet and we decide to cancel it today. How will that be justified by the equation? Will we suddenly gain a US$1 Million asset or loose a US$1 Million liability?

Answer (score 1):

Treasury Stock is included in Common Stock (it was previously issued as common stock and then bought back), so the retirement of treasury stock would also decrease common stock accordingly. There may also be changes in additional paid-in capital and retained earnings depending on the specifics of the transaction.

So the equation still balances because all of the affected accounts are equity accounts (liabilities and assets are not affected).